# Symfony retrieve object after form submission

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I would like to understand the difference between :

```
$form->handleRequest($request); 
if ($form->isValid()) { 
     //access data that was submitted by the user using:
      $objectHoldingDataSubmittedIntheForm = $form->getData();        
}
```

and

```
        $form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class, $objectHoldingDataSubmittedIntheForm);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
//access data that was submitted by the user using:
           // $objectHoldingDataSubmittedIntheForm holds by itself all the submitted data
      }
```

My question is that, if handlerequest fills the object that was passed to the form with data submitted by the user, then why do we need  `$form->getData();` to get submitted data ? can't we just use the object that was passed to the form since it now holds all the info?

Comment: To clarify, how did you get `$objectHoldingDataSubmittedIntheForm` that you pass to `$this->createForm()` in your 2nd example ?

Comment: `$form->getData()` is useful when dealing with arrays.  If you pass an object into the create form stuff then there is no need to use it.  I have seen it used in some tutorials and examples but I'm pretty sure it was used because the author did not understand.

Comment: @AymDev it was a new object that i created.

Comment: @Cerad ok got it thanks :) what do you mean by "dealing with arrays?"

Comment: @Mirachalak You don't see it very often but instead of an object you can actually pass a good ole fashion array to the form component.  Nice for small forms where you maybe don't want to go through the trouble of creating a data object.  In this scenario, the original array does not get updated with posted information like objects do.  You need to use getData to get a fresh copy with all the new values.

Comment: `$form->getData()` is also useful for 'create' forms (to create a new entity), where the form is bound to a class, but you don't pass in an object when creating the form. The form then creates the object for you and you can use `$form->getData()` to retrieve it.